# GROUP_CONCAT inside the WHERE IN condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I need to get the `id` of all the attributes and in order not to request the database 2 times, I want to do everything with one query, but for some reason I don't get the desired result, there is probably some nuance here that I don't know about.

The query in the database looks like this:

```
SELECT term_taxonomy_id, taxonomy 
FROM DahVJ9_term_taxonomy
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.term_taxonomy_id SEPARATOR ",") 
      FROM DahVJ9_term_relationships tr
      INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM DahVJ9_posts 
                 WHERE post_type = "product" AND ID = 19387
                 ) p ON p.ID = tr.object_id
      )
```

The request goes to the `WooCommerce` database (although this does not play a role for the question).
A query that returns a comma-separated `id` inside `WHERE`.
If I put these `ids` in an external request, I get the result that I need.
However, they do not work together (only the first line is returned, instead of all the `ids` of which are in the condition).

What did I miss?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a comma-delimited string. Is `term_taxonomy_id` also a comma-separated string?

Comment: The `IN` condition requires it to be a comma-delimited string, and also have the exact same items in the same order. Since you didn't use `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT`, the order can't be predicted, so this is unlikely to work.

Comment: You probably don't need `GROUP_CONCAT`. Just use `WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (SELECT tr.term_taxonomy_id ...)`

Comment: Indeed it helped, thanks. But you probably wanted to say not `ORDER BY`, but `GROUP BY`?

Comment: No, I meant `ORDER BY`. If `term_taxonomy_id` is `1,3` and `GROUP_CONCAT(tr.term_taxonomy_id)` returns `3,1`, they won't match.

Comment: I got it, thank you. I just substituted `ORDER BY` in my example and it didn't work, but `GROUP BY` worked. I guess I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this. Just join the 3 tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.term_taxonomy_id, tt.taxonomy
FROM DahVJ9_term_taxonomy AS tt
JOIN DahVJ9_term_relationships AS tr ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN DahVJ9_posts AS p ON p.id = tr.object_id
WHERE p.post_type = "product" AND p.ID = 19387
```

And as you can see, there's no need to join with a subquery, you can just join with the table directly.

Comment: Using DISTINCT after a 3 table join would be very inefficient. The operator IN would perform better.

Comment: In my experience, MySQL often implements `IN (SELECT ...)` very poorly, so I try to avoid it.